# ElasticSearch: Document exists but not found

Tags: elasticsearch

When I insert new documents into my index, I don't get them...
Here is my query:

```
{ query: 
   { bool: 
      { must: 
         [ { match: { name: 'Here is the name' } },
           { parent_id: { type: 'type', id: 'parentID' } } ] } } }
```

Just before, I have to add a lot ( around 10 000 documents ), and I can get some documents, and not others, very weird...

Sometimes, I don't the document when I query from the dev tools, it seems to work better after a POST /_refresh, but I still don't have all of them later

Here is how I build my index:

```
PUT /myIndex
{
   "settings":{
      "index":{
         "number_of_shards":1,
         "refresh_interval" : "-1",
         "number_of_replicas" : 0
      }
   },
   "mappings":{ // MY MAPPING HERE }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your settings you have `"refresh_interval" : "-1"`, which means that automatic refreshes are **turned off**. In this case every time you want to refresh your index (make your documents visible to search), you need to call `POST /myIndex/_refresh`.

Your `refresh_interval` value must be `> 0` for documents to be automatically refreshed. e.g.

```
PUT /myIndex/_settings
{ "refresh_interval": "1s" }
```

Refresh automatically every second.